# ggplot - horizontal bar plot sort with largest at top

Tags: r, ggplot2

with a dataframe like below

```
text <- "
name,miles
tata_zest,99.8
toyota_prius,100.0
honda_civic,99.9
toyota_corolla,100.0
tata_safari,99.1
nissan_sunny,100.0
"
df <- read.table(textConnection(text), sep=",", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I need to have a bar plot for the `miles` for the various `name`s such that they are sorted in descending order of `miles`. So I do the following.

```
df <- df %>%
  arrange(desc(miles))
df$name <- factor(df$name, levels = df$name)

ggplot() +
  geom_col(data=df, aes(x=name, y=miles) )
```

This gives me a bar chart like below - nice and great. The bars are sorted in descending order. I want to generate horizontal bar charts with the same data. By adding `coord_flip()` this could be achieved. However the challenge  is that in the horizontal bar charts I want to have the bar with largest  value at the top and the smallest value at the bottom.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just change that `arrange(desc(miles))` to `arrange(miles)`?

Comment: The first or lowest value on the y-axis is always on the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

would something like this work for you? More or less identical to [Tino 's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48336193/ggplot-horizontal-bar-plot-sort-with-largest-at-top#comment83657538_48336193)

```
df <- arrange(df, miles)
df$name <- factor(df$name, levels = df$name)
ggplot(df, aes(name, miles, fill = name)) + geom_col() + coord_flip() +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette="Spectral")
```

[image: plot]